# strlen() not working as intended - no errors

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if the `$field['message']` is less than 5 letters and then check again if it's more than 100 letters, but I'm not passing the first rule - it's output the result for the `$field['message'] < 5` - why?

```
} elseif (strlen($field['message'] < 5)) {
  // some output for < 5 case 
} elseif (strlen($field['message'] > 100)) {
  // some output for > 100 case
}
```

And a result is that if I use less or more than 5 letters, I'm getting the same output for `< 5` case.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it because of the array?

Comment: Watch the parentheses `elseif (strlen($field['message']) < 5)`

Comment: Thank you, thank you... It's silly, but I wasn't noticed that :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> elseif (strlen($field['message'] < 5))

You put the parentheses in wrong places. Should be:

```
elseif (strlen($field['message']) < 5)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this question just be closed a typo?

Comment: oh my gosh... thanks! :)

Comment: @JohnConde It's not a typo I think. OP just doesnt understand it I think.

Comment: @JohnConde you can vote as you like, but imho this one wasn't a strict typo, hence my answer instead of nuke drop.